# Add multiple lag of a column at once in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, partition

Assume I have this data:

```
A.    B.  
1.    2
3.    4
5.    6
7.    8
9.    10
```

Using window function I can easily add any lag of a column to this data, for example for lag 1 I do this:

```
lag(A, 1, 0) over ( partition by B) as lag1 from myTable;
```

I can change 1 to any number and add any other lag, however how can I add let's say lags 1,2 and 3 at the same time. I mean one way is to include the above statements for different lag separated by comma, however what if I want to do it for 20 lags, then the method is not scalable.

Comment: I believe each LAG() expression can return only one value. I'm afraid you'll have to repeat the expression if you want results for multiple lagging rows.

Comment: I know I was wondering if there is any smart or fast way to do this.

Comment: Try a text editor with a copy & paste feature.

Comment: Can you also _specify_ the expected result?